# Failed to build a new project in Android Studio.The build.gradle seems error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I build up a new project in AS,it came a error like this:
[this is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhMnN.png)
But I never come to this error before,it suddenly doesn't work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there  `*//Do not place your application dependencies*` etc.... it clearly states not to put any of your app dependency there, and your `build.gradle( Module: app)` is also missing. You must put your dependencies in `build.gradle( Module: app)`. Try to rebuild your project. `Build > Rebuild Project` or if that doesn't helps, close Android Studio, go to your AndroidProjects folder and delete the folder called `Gradle` and the restart Android Studio. Hope that helps.